# Update global value from one php function and make it available to another function within the same class

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel excel and I want to pass data to headings functions. But currently data is not available at the moment.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use DB;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class MatrixExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
    protected $building_ids = [], $amenities_list = [], $property ;
    public $a_list_only;

    public function __construct($building_ids, $amenities_list, $property, $a_list_only = [])
    {
        $this->building_ids = $building_ids;
        $this->amenities_list = $amenities_list;
        $this->property = $property;
        $this->a_list_only = $a_list_only;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        $non_unit = DB::table('non_units as nu')
            ->join('buildings as b','b.id','=','nu.building_id')
            ->where('b.property_id',$this->property->id)
            ->pluck('nu.id');

        $query = \DB::table('units_amenities_values')
            ->join('units', 'units.id', 'units_amenities_values.unit_id')
            ->join('floors', 'floors.id', 'units.floor_id')
            ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', 'floors.building_id')
            ->join('properties', 'properties.id', 'buildings.property_id')
            ->leftJoin('amenity_values', 'amenity_values.id', 'units_amenities_values.amenity_value_id')
            ->leftJoin('amenities', 'amenities.id', 'amenity_values.amenity_id')
            ->leftJoin('categories', 'amenities.category_id', 'categories.id');
        if ($this->property->availability_file == 1 || $this->property->availability_file == 3) {
            $query->leftJoin('availabilities', 'availabilities.unit_id', 'units.id');
            $query->select('units_amenities_values.id as uav_id', 'units_amenities_values.uav_status', 'units_amenities_values.deleted_at as uav_deleted_at', 'amenities.id as amenity_id', 'amenities.amenity_name', 'amenity_values.initial_amenity_value', 'amenity_values.amenity_value', 'amenity_values.status as av_status', 'floors.floor', 'units.id as unit_id', 'units.unit_number', 'units.unit_rent', 'units.stack', 'units.unit_note', 'amenities.category_id', 'buildings.id as building_id', 'buildings.building_number', 'availabilities.status as avail_status','categories.category_name');
        } else {
            $query->select('units_amenities_values.id as uav_id', 'units_amenities_values.uav_status', 'units_amenities_values.deleted_at as uav_deleted_at', 'amenities.id as amenity_id', 'amenities.amenity_name', 'amenity_values.initial_amenity_value', 'amenity_values.amenity_value', 'amenity_values.status as av_status', 'floors.floor', 'units.id as unit_id', 'units.unit_number', 'units.unit_rent', 'units.stack', 'units.unit_note', 'amenities.category_id', 'buildings.id as building_id', 'buildings.building_number','categories.category_name');
        }
        $query->where('amenities.property_id', $this->property->id)
            ->whereIn('buildings.id', $this->building_ids)
            ->whereNull('buildings.deleted_at');
        if(!in_array('-1',$this->amenities_list)){
            $query->whereIn('amenities.id',$this->amenities_list);
        }
        if(!empty($this->building_ids)){
            $query->whereIn('buildings.id', $this->building_ids);
        }else{
            $query->where('buildings.property_id', $this->property->id);
        }

        $res = $query
            ->orderByRaw('LENGTH(amenity_name)', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('amenity_name')
            ->get();

        $data = $res->groupBy('unit_id');

        $selected_data = [];
        $included_amenity_ids = [];
        foreach($res as $rk => $rv){
            if( (!in_array($rv->amenity_id,$included_amenity_ids) && in_array($rv->amenity_id, $this->amenities_list)) || (!in_array($rv->amenity_id,$included_amenity_ids) && in_array('-1', $this->amenities_list)) ){
                $included_amenity_ids[] = $rv->amenity_id;
                $selected_data[$rv->category_id]['category_name'] = $rv->category_name;
                $selected_data[$rv->category_id]['amenities'][$rv->amenity_id] = $rv->amenity_name;
            }
        }
        ksort($selected_data);
        $am_lists_only = [];
        foreach($selected_data as $sk => $sv){
            $am_lists_only = $am_lists_only + $sv['amenities'];
        }
        $ex_data = $item = [];
        foreach($data as $k => $v){
            $item = [
                'Bldg' => $v[0]->building_number,
                'Unit' => (is_numeric($v[0]->unit_number))?(int)$v[0]->unit_number:$v[0]->unit_number,
                'Floor' =>(is_numeric($v[0]->floor))?(int)$v[0]->floor:$v[0]->floor,
                'Stack' => (is_numeric($v[0]->stack))?(int)$v[0]->stack:$v[0]->stack
            ];
            foreach ($am_lists_only as $ak => $av) {
                $this->a_list_only[] = $av;
                $current_val = "";
                foreach ($v as $vk => $vv) {
                    if ($vv->amenity_id == $ak) {
                        $current_val = $vv->amenity_value;
                    }
                }
                $item[$av] = $current_val;
            }
            $ex_data[] = $item;
        }
        return $ex_data;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        $commonn_header_arr = ['Bldg', 'Unit', 'Floor', 'Stack'];
        dd($this->a_list_only);

        $second_row_header = array_merge($commonn_header_arr, $this->a_list_only);
        return $second_row_header;
    }

}
```

Here, you could see I have initialized  `$this->a_list_only` on construct and update this array on

```
 foreach ($am_lists_only as $ak => $av) {
                $this->a_list_only[] = $av;
                $current_val = "";
                foreach ($v as $vk => $vv) {
                    if ($vv->amenity_id == $ak) {
                        $current_val = $vv->amenity_value;
                    }
                }
                $item[$av] = $current_val;
            }
```

But, the updated array is not available in headings function.

Comment: it is probably running the `headings` method before `array` is called

Comment: Any way to make this work? Moving headings above array function does not seems to be working.

Comment: that wouldn't change anything, the position of methods defined in the class doesn't matter ... you are not the one "calling" this code, the excel library is ... so you will probably have to do some debugging to figure out the call flow/order here